# Is it possible to reference an unsaved query?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Frequently I drop ready-made queries into Access.  Create > Query Design > SQL, and paste the code directly to the text window.  [image]

Generally I do not save these queries in Access because I have to minimize the clutter of one-time, ad hoc reporting.  I wrote a macro for Access that will automatically save the results of an established query...

```vb
Sub qry40T_export()
'export the results of the query "qry40T" to local excel file
'prompt the user for the save location
'name the file "qry40T_output.xls"

'initialize variable type
Dim save_dir As String
save_dir = "dunno_yet"

'initialize default filename
savefile_name = "qry40T_output.xls"

'prompt user for save location
save_dir = InputBox(Prompt:="Save query export to the following directory:", Title:="Save file to:", _
Default:="F:\QUERYDATA\")

'validate user submitted
If save_dir = "" Then
    'user chose 'Cancel'
    Exit Sub
End If

'compose full save filename
fullsavefile_name = save_dir & savefile_name

'edit error treatment
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'export the query
'overwrite "qry40T_output.xls"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qry40T", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", fullsavefile_name, False, "", , acExportQualityPrint

'success
MsgBox ("Export successful.")

'restore error treatment
On Error GoTo 0

'error handling resolution
subexit:
Exit Sub

'error handling message
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Error$
Resume subexit

End Sub
```

...but now I would like to apply this same process to an unsaved query.  Is that possible?  My guess is that the code would look something like this: `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, OpenQuery(1), "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", fullsavefile_name, False, "", , acExportQualityPrint`, but I can't seem to find the right syntax.

Comment: No, you cannot output an unsaved query, but you can create a query that outputs to Excel.

Comment: just like @Remou has said + you can output a query into any `recordset` type object ( it does not necessarily have to be Excel )

Comment: For example, this is ADO but DAO is also a good option : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092282/excel-vba-copyfromrecordset-slows-when-copying-over-100-columns/22095760#22095760

Comment: It sounds like your comment is more like an answer.  Maybe you should repost as an answer so users can vote-up?

Answer (score 1):

Since these are 'throw-away' queries and don't need to be saved, you could save them with the same query name every time.

For example, you can *always* save your temporary queries as "qry40T".  Then, your macro will always work and save the results of whatever query is saved in qry40T at the time.

Comment: The only possible exception to this is if multiple people had the database open at the same time, in which case they might be overwriting the same query(s). This is easily got around by splitting the database though.

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem, but the question didn't imply there would be multiple users.  Even so, splitting the database would only work if either every user had their own copy of the front-end or the queries were saved with the user's windows user name, .e.g `QryCust_BFDA`.

Comment: True, but I always think an access front end is a bit overkill if there's only one user. I used your suggestion of adding a windows username to the queries in my last multiuser database, as everyone accesses it through a remote network rather than locally so splitting it traditionally was impractical.